# passing dropdownlist value from one page to another page

Tags: php

I want to do like in [this website](http://www.renganathan.in) when a user selects the value from (to) and (from) dropdown list and also select departure and return from this page then he moves to the next page and dropdownlist in next page are automatically populated with the value selected by the user in first page. My question is how dropdownlist in second page are displayed?

```
<form id="form_1" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="pad1">
            <h3>Find Your Trip</h3>
            <p>
                <label for="select">Trip Type</label>
                <select name="select4" id="select">
                    <option value="choose">Choose</option>
                    <option value="one way">One way</option>
                    <option value="round trip">Round Trip</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <div class="row_select">
                <p>
                    From:
                    <select name="select">
                        <option value="" selected>:: Departure ::</option>
                        <option value="36">ABBOTTABAD</option>
                        <option value="6" >BAHAWALPUR</option>
                        <option value="18" >CHINIOT</option>
                        <option value="14" >DERA GHAZI KHAN</option>
                        <option value="16" >FAISALABAD</option>
                        <option value="34" >GUJRANWALA</option>
                        <option value="33" >GUJRAT</option>
                        <option value="53" >JHELUM</option>
                        <option value="13" >KARACHI</option>
                        <option value="5" >MULTAN</option>
                        <option value="35" >MURREE</option>
                        <option value="25" >PESHAWAR</option>
                        <option value="22" >RAWALPINDI</option>
                        <option value="22" >LAHORE</option>
                    </select>
                </p>
                <p>
                    To:    
                    <label></label>
                    <select name="select2">
                        <option value="" selected>:: Arrival ::</option>
                        <option value="36">ABBOTTABAD</option>
                        <option value="53" >JHELUM</option>
                        <option value="13" >KARACHI</option>
                        <option value="53" >MULTAN</option>
                        <option value="3" >MURREE</option>
                        <option value="5" >PESHAWAR</option>
                        <option value="2" >RAWALPINDI</option>
                        <option value="2" >LAHORE</option>
                    </select><br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="row_select">
                <p>
                    Arrival:<br>
                    <input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31"><br>

                     Destination:                
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="date" name="bday2" min="2000-01-02"><br>
                    <span class="cols">Adult:<br>
                        <select name="select3">
                            <option>&nbsp;</option>
                            <option>...</option>
                            <option>...</option>
                        </select>
                    </span><br><br>
                    <span class="cols pad_left1">
                        <a href="page2.php" class="button">BUY</a>                 
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
    </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Comment: a second page contain same form as in page 1

Comment: Show your code what you did to achieve your task.

Comment: you can store your values in a session variable and use them in your second page

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form id="form_1" action="#" method="post">
     <div class="pad1">
     <h3>Find Your Trip </h3>
     <p>
     <label for="select">Trip Type</label>
     <select name="select4" id="select">
     <?php echo $_POST["select4"]; ?>!<br>
     <option value="choose">Choose</option>
     <option value="one way">One way</option>
     <option value="round trip">Round Trip</option>
     </select>
     </p>
     <div class="row_select">
     <p>From:
     <select name="select">
     <?php echo $_POST["select"]; ?>!<br>
     <option value="" selected>:: Departure ::</option>
     <option value="36">ABBOTTABAD</option>
     <option value="6">BAHAWALPUR</option>
     <option value="6">BAHAWALPUR</option>
     <option value="18">CHINIOT</option>
     <option value="14">DERA GHAZI KHAN</option>
     <option value="16">FAISALABAD</option>
     <option value="34">GUJRANWALA</option>
     <option value="33">GUJRAT</option>
     <option value="53">JHELUM</option>
     <option value="13">KARACHI</option>
     <option value="5">MULTAN</option>
     <option value="35">MURREE</option>
     <option value="25">PESHAWAR</option>
     <option value="22">RAWALPINDI</option>
     <option value="22">LAHORE</option>
     </select>
     </p>
     <p> To:
     <label></label>
     <select name="select2">
 <?php echo $_POST["select2"];?>!<br>
     <option value="" selected>:: Arrival ::</option>
     <option value="36">ABBOTTABAD</option>
     <option value="53">JHELUM</option>
     <option value="13">KARACHI</option>
     <option value="53">MULTAN</option>
     <option value="3">MURREE</option>
     <option value="5">PESHAWAR</option>
     <option value="2">RAWALPINDI</option>
     <option value="2">LAHORE</option>
     </select>
     <br>
     </p>
     </div>
     <div class="row_select">
     <p>Arrival:<br>
     <input type="date" name="bday" max="1979-12-31">
     <?php echo $_POST["bday"];?>!<br>
     <br>
     Destination:                
     </p>
     <p>
     <input type="date" name="bday2" min="2000-01-02">
     <?php echo $_POST["bday2"];?>!<br>
     <br>
     <span class="cols">Adult:<br>
     <select name="select3">
     <option>&nbsp;</option>
     <option></option>
     <option></option>
     </select>
     </span><br>
     <br>
     <span class="cols pad_left1"><a href="page2.php" class="button">BUY</a>                 </span></p>
     </div>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     </div>
     </fieldset> 
     </form>
```

Comment: this is my second page